# Office.js : How to call a function from function-file that's generated with angular CLI

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, office-js

I used angular-cli to create a new project and added ng-office-ui-fabric and dependencies to the project. I added https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js to index.html and added polyfills to angular.json and all was well.

In Word i can sideload the add-in just fine and the taskpanes i created get loaded and are working.

But in the manifest there's a function-file that allows a button on the ribbon to call a javascript function directly from the function-file.html. I could add a js and html file as asset to the project but I want to program in TS, not JS. I figured adding a page to the project and defining the functions inside that component should work too. But adding that page to the manifest as functionfile doesn't seem to work.

so my question, if office.js is able to call a javascript function from a separate html file, how would i publish that same function on a routed angular page from a component that i wrote in typescript instead? do i need to export it anywhere? is it the late loading? why doesn't it work? or should i define those functions in main.ts?

Comment: This is the Microsoft doc on function-file. As said, how do i put that in a singlepage angular-cli page.  https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/functionfile

Answer (score 3):

The function-file.html that is opened from a ribbon button opens in an entirely separate instance of Internet Explorer from the task pane, and thus an entirely separate JavaScript engine and execution context and session. They don't even share session storage. They can communicate with each other only Local Storage or by some common server-side data storage.

When you are using a single-page framework for an Office add-in that has a custom ribbon button, you basically have two choices:

(1) Deviate from pure single-page design and create a page and function solely as the launch target of the button. This is, in effect, a separate app that is hosted in the same domain as the main single-page app. For simplicity, I recommend this option.

(2) Include the function that you want the ribbon to launch in your main app and assign a route to it. Use the route as the URL for the function in the app's manifest. But note that if you do this, a complete second instance of your single-page app is loaded in the IE instance that is launched by the ribbon button. The start up logic of the app would have to be designed so that when it is launched by the special route, it does NOT try to load the standard starting view that it would load in the task pane.

Comment: I would rather have a single project and site for both type of functions. So in my manifest i have `<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction"><FunctionName>MyFun</FunctionName></Action>` where the functionfile points to `https://mysite/#/functions`. My app inits regardless of the existance of an object Office so i can connect to mysite/#/functions in a browser just fine. so the route works. But from office, pressing the button has no effect at all. I assume that the MyFun function should be inside the component like it were to be called from a buttonpress on the page, correct? how do i debug that?

Comment: @kjoetools I am having same issue rite now . Do you have solution to this?